# T-SQL Outer JOIN like oracle syntax (+)

Tags: t-sql

I've to join 3 tables.

```
select u.*, c1.name, c2.name
users u, country c1, country c2
where u.country_id = c1.country_id(+)
AND u.bank_country_id = c2.country_id(+)
```

The symbol (+) in oracle means that I want a Left Outer Join on both that table (c1 and c2)

How to do the same in T-SQL?

Comment: You shouldn't be using the (deprecated)  `(+)` operator in Oracle anyway

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: yes.. I know it's deprecated, but it seems lovely. Do you think there is any strong reason for avoiding it?

Comment: Oracle recommends not doing it. Additionally all the reasons why you shouldn't be using the old, outdated implicit (inner) joins in the WHERE clause also apply here. Get used to the modern explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Best to try and stick as close to ansi standard as possible.

Comment: "It seems lovely" doesn't scale well. Especially when preceded by "I know it's deprecated". [Relevant old Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/queries006.htm#sthref2282)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select u.*, c1.name, c2.name
from users u
left outer join country c1 on u.country_id = c1.country_id
left outer join country c2 on u.bank_country_id = c2.country_id
```